# mysql insert ignore, replace or update on duplicate - did insert?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using php to 'insert ignore' a row into my database. Is there a way to find out whether a row was inserted?

the code looks like this:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table (key_a, key_b) VALUES (?, ?)'))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', 'hello', 'world');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: [`mysqli::$affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if($stmt->execute())
{
echo "Success";

}
else
{
echo "Error";

}
```

Also check [mysqli::$affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

```
$mysqli->affected_rows
```

> mysqli::$affected_rows -- mysqli_affected_rows — Gets the number of
>   affected rows in a previous MySQL operation

Comment: actually affected_rows was very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: `$mysqli->affected_rows`

[Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.affected-rows.html):

```php
/* update rows */
$mysqli->query("UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's correct, but several correct answers at the same time so I took the most comprehensive one. Voted your's up tho

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature where you can define what to do if your insert fails because of some constrains like unique_key or primary_key being inserted twice.

On that cases, cases, you can trap such errors.
If the query inserts normally, it won't execute this block.
If the query fails, the block will be executed.

Now, you may tweak this feature.
For example, in your table, add one insert_attempts columns with default 0 (zero) value.
And try to execute:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (key_a, key_b)
VALUES (?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    insert_attempts = insert_attempts+1
;
```

After all records are successful; SELECT the rows with insert_attempt > 0.

Comment: thank you for your answer. though this will work I would have to change my table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the execute() method will return a true or false, so I would suggest more sth. like this (also note that u need to do this before you close the connection):

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
echo "success" 
} 
else
{
echo "Error"
}
```

, also consider to fetch the statement to see how many lines were affected. You can do that with mysqli_stmt_affected_rows(statement), it will give you the lines affected. If you use it, it couls look like this:

```
int mysqli_stmt_affected_rows ( mysqli_stmt $stmt )
```

also read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's correct, but several correct answers at the same time. Voted your's up tho